# WSO2 ESB Expose a REST API keeping URI part

Tags: rest, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

Say I have a REST API hosted on a webserver:
someone.com/api/

I want to expose this REST API through a proxy service using WSO2 ESB. 
esb.com/api/

It should forward whatever is after esb.com/api/. So if I hit:

esb.com/api/param1/param2

It should hit the real service using:

someone.com/api/param1/param2

How do I pass the URI parts to the real webservice from a proxy service?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use Proxy services for REST API. Proxy Services are for the Web Services. Use **API** s avialable in WSO2 ESB which are similar to proxy services and intended for REST API. [This](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/10/implementing-restful-services-wso2-esb) Oxygen Tank article and [this](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/rest_api_samples.html) sample document will be useful for you.

Comment: Can you please explain how to I send the URL to the destination REST API? For example, how do I send the /param1/param2 to the <send>? <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>